# Refreshing angular page is taking to another route

Tags: angular, routes, refresh

I joined a team with a massive system in production. I have to figure out why when refreshing the page is taking me to another page in the system.

I have checked other modules of the system to compare but the structure of all of them differs to some degree because they are developed by other teams.

I do not understand why refreshing the page takes to another URL within the system, could somebody help me understand please?

Comment: One suggestion is to check any guards on the routing files down the whole tree to that page.  A lot of time there is redirect logic in guards if specific conditions aren't met.

Comment: what is your web server? can you explain clearly?

Comment: It might be cause by web server instead Angular routing.